# Export raster layer in python to specific folder

Tags: qgis, python, raster

I am trying to export existing raster layers as tif files. I just want to avoid saving each raster manually. this is the code I am trying to use, but it doesn't seem to work:

```py
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
import os
import sys

layers = iface.layerTreeView().selectedLayers()
for layer in layers:
    output='Desktop'%layer.name%'.tif'
```

As specified in a comment below, I modified my code to this:

```py
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
import os
import sys


layers = iface.layerTreeView().selectedLayers()

for layer in layers:
     file_name = 'D:\tif' + layer.name() + '.tif'
     file_writer = QgsRasterFileWriter(file_name)
     pipe = QgsRasterPipe()
     provider = layer.dataProvider()

     if not pipe.set(provider.clone()):
        print "Cannot set pipe provider"
     continue

     file_writer.writeRaster(
        pipe,
        provider.xSize(),
        provider.ySize(),
        provider.extent(),
        provider.crs())
```

I can't seem to get it to work and I am not getting any error.

I already selected the layers and it still does not work.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Your code doesn't work because you're not doing anything in your `for` loop (except setting a file name).

Saving a raster is a bit tedious, afaik. Here is a sample code I gathered from varied sources; I didn't test it, so it might need some adjustments. It relies on the [`QgsRasterPipe`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsRasterPipe.html) and [`QgsRasterFileWriter`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsRasterFileWriter.html) classes.

```
layers = iface.layerTreeView().selectedLayers()
for layer in layers:
    file_name = '/full/raster/path/' + layer.name() + '.tif'
    file_writer = QgsRasterFileWriter(file_name)
    pipe = QgsRasterPipe()
    provider = layer.dataProvider()

    if not pipe.set(provider.clone()):
        print "Cannot set pipe provider"
        continue

    file_writer.writeRaster(
        pipe,
        provider.xSize(),
        provider.ySize(),
        provider.extent(),
        provider.crs())
```

Note: I'd love to know if there is a simpler way to save rasters!

EDIT: added dummy path in `file_name` (full path is required).

Comment: I tried your code, but like mine, it doesn't work. If you could please try it out, that would be awesome. Thanks.

Comment: Well, I just tried it and it works like a charm (QGIS 2.8). However, you have to put the full path to your new raster in `file_name` (including the name itself). If you still have an issue with this correction, please copy the error message in your next comment. EDIT: I didn't explicitely put it in my answer, but the code I provided replaces only the two last lines of your code. You still have to write the imports and `layers = iface.layerTreeView().selectedLayers()`.

Comment: Sorry to bother so much, but could you tell me which imports are needed? I am really new to this. Thanks!

Comment: One auick question would the imports I ised in my first post work for this code?

Comment: Sorry, no import is actually needed if you run this script from the QGIS Python console. If you run it externally, you'll probably need `from qgis.core import *`.

Comment: Can you please tell me which importa I have to use, since I am really new to this? Thanks, I really appreciate it.

Comment: from what I can understand, I would only need to add the full path where I want to save the raster file, since I already am using the layer's name as the name I want to save the raster file. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: when I run the script in the console, it runs but gives me no error and does nothing. I posted the code I am currently using in the question.

Comment: Your code seems to be fine. I forgot to mention one thing: you have to select the raster(s) you want to export in the TOC (QGIS left panel).

Comment: I added a picture, so you can see what I am doing. I already selected the layers and it still doesn't work.

Comment: By 'select', I mean that the layer must be highlighted (just click on the layer's name). This is different than activating the layers: your layers are activated but not selected.

Comment: I did as you said, but still nothing. I replaced the image again.

Comment: Well, I'm lost then, sorry. I have no idea why it doesn't work on your computer, especially since there is no error message. I can only encourage you to check your path and your copy of the script (indentation is critical with Python).

Comment: I am finally getting an error that I am getting: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:/tif/SaveRaster.py", line 15, in <module>
    if not pipe.set(provider.clone()):
AttributeError: 'QgsVectorDataProvider' object has no attribute 'clone'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38438/discussion-between-user1905507-and-armoraer).