# Adding and saving layers from QGIS console

Tags: raster, pyqgis, vector

I have a data-set of **.tif** satellite images and **.geoJSON** labels corresponding to them.
I am trying to iterate over the satellite images,plot the **geoJSON** labels and save them as **.jpeg** images.

However,only the first image is being saved correctly.The others are either completely blank or have very little of the original .tif image on them.
I am very new to QGIS.

Here is my code

```
for el in [1,3,4,7,8,9]:
    iface.addRasterLayer("Path/RGB-PanSharpen_AOI_2_Vegas_img"+str(el)+".tif", "Image") #Adding Image
    iface.addVectorLayer('Path/buildings_AOI_2_Vegas_img'+str(el)+'.geojson','Label','ogr') #Adding labels
    eMenu =iface.viewMenu()
    eMenu.actions() [11].trigger() #Zooming in to layer
    iface.mapCanvas().saveAsImage("Desktop\Im"+str(el)+".jpeg",None,"jpeg") #Saving
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().removeAllMapLayers() #Clearing canvas
```

I am using QGIS 2.14.20-Essen

Comment: `eMenu.actions() [11].trigger() #Zooming in to layer` has a space before the zoom level

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/189735/how-to-iterate-over-layers-and-export-them-as-png-images-with-pyqgis-in-a-standa/189825#189825

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that enough time delay was not being provided and hence I got half loaded images.

Here is the final code if it helps anyone else-

```
eleArr=[1,3,4,7,8,9]
ind=-1
from PyQt4.QtCore import QTimer

def AddRastLayer():
   global eleArr
   global ind
   ind+=1
   el=eleArr[ind]   
   if(ind<=4):
        iface.addRasterLayer("Path/RGB-PanSharpen_AOI_2_Vegas_img"+str(el)+".tif", "layer of "+str(el))
        QTimer.singleShot(1000, AddVectLayer)
def AddVectLayer():
   global eleArr
   global ind
   el=eleArr[ind]
   iface.addVectorLayer('Path/AOI_2_Vegas_img'+str(el)+'.geojson','Label '+str(el),'ogr')  
   QTimer.singleShot(1000, ZoomLayer)
def ZoomLayer():
   global eleArr
   global ind
   eMenu =iface.viewMenu()
   eMenu.actions()[11].trigger()
   QTimer.singleShot(1000, SaveLayer)   
def SaveLayer():
   global eleArr
   global ind
   el=eleArr[ind]
   iface.mapCanvas().saveAsImage("Path\ Im"+str(el)+".jpeg",None,"jpeg")
   QTimer.singleShot(1000, RemLayer)
def RemLayer():
   global eleArr
   global ind
   el=eleArr[ind]
   QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().removeAllMapLayers()
   QTimer.singleShot(1000, AddRastLayer)
AddRastLayer()
```