# mapCanvas.saveAsImage() doesn't work properly within loop in standalone script (only .PGW)

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, standalone, qgsmapcanvas, refresh

I have a problem with the export of QGIS 3 interface screenshots. I run stand-alone scripts and one of them launches QGIS and runs `script.py` with the following code :

```
mapCanvas = iface.mapCanvas()

selectedfeatures= layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest(request))

for feat in selectedfeatures:
    layer.selectByIds([feat.id()])
    mapCanvas.zoomToSelected(layer)
    mapCanvas.refresh()
    mapCanvas.saveAsImage(path)
```

with the command line :
`qgis-bin.exe --nologo --project path_project --code script.py`

But the images are not always saved (random files are saved, sometimes nothing), only the .pgw like if the interface had no time to refresh... I already read solutions like with refresh SLOTS, or QTimer but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Asimilar question was already answer for QGIS v2.x. Have you already tried such solution? https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/189825/4972

Comment: Yes as I explain it in my question the QTimer solution doesn't work for me. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For people who want to know the answer, the difficulty for me was to use mapCanvasRefreshed() correctly. You have to initialize the process with a zoomToFeatureIds so that the signal is sent to your main function.

Comment: Could you explain in greater detail?