# Batch export of layers as individual PNG files in QGIS 3.4?

Tags: qgis, export, batch, png

I have hundreds of layers. I'd like to be able export each one as a PNG. I can do this by selecting one, and going to project, export map to image, calculate from layer -> select layer -> save. Is there any way I can export all of them as seperate PNG files as a batch process?

I have made progress with the python code below. Unfortunately they are all just white 5k png files.

```py
# create image
img = QImage(QSize(800, 800), QImage.Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied)

# set background color
color = QColor(255, 255, 255, 255)
img.fill(color.rgba())

# create painter
p = QPainter()
p.begin(img)
p.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

# create map settings
ms = QgsMapSettings()
ms.setBackgroundColor(color)

# set layers to render
#layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('stream_order')
#ms.setLayers([layer[0]])


#get all map layers:

layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()

#loop through layers

for layer in layers:

    # set extent
    rect = QgsRectangle(ms.fullExtent())
    rect.scale(1.1)
    ms.setExtent(rect)

    # set ouptut size
    ms.setOutputSize(img.size())

    # setup qgis map renderer
    render = QgsMapRendererCustomPainterJob(ms, p)
    render.start()
    render.waitForFinished()
    p.end()

    # save the image
    img.save("C:/imageexport/"+layer.name()+".png")

    print('image saved')
```

replacing `rect = QgsRectangle(ms.fullExtent())` with `rect = QgsRectangle(layer.extent())` seemed like the logical solution if the issue was the extent being too big, but this just causes QGIS to crash instantly.

I tried the following code and just got a completely black image.

```
#image_location = os.path.join(QgsProject.instance().homePath(), "render.png")

vlayer = iface.activeLayer()
#vlayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("id_")[0]
options = QgsMapSettings()
options.setLayers([vlayer])
options.setBackgroundColor(QColor(255, 255, 255))
options.setOutputSize(QSize(2000, 2000))
options.setExtent(vlayer.extent())

render = QgsMapRendererParallelJob(options)

def finished():
    img = render.renderedImage()
    img.save("C:/Users/smallfing.FINGBIAL/Documents/SHEFFIELD/Road PNG Export/render.png","png")
    #img.save(image_location, "png")
    print("saved")

render.finished.connect(finished)

render.start()
```

Comment: To do an automation task this I think you should use PyQGIS.

Comment: Perhaps this [answer might help](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/189735/iterating-over-layers-and-export-them-as-png-images-with-pyqgis-in-a-standalone/333486#333486).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have tried with some python code (above) but these all come out as blank.

Answer (score 0):

Try substituting:

```
render = QgsMapRendererCustomPainterJob(ms, p)
```

for:

```
render = QgsMapRendererParallelJob(ms)
```