# RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QgsPrintLayout has been deleted

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

When I am running the code in QGIS python console, I am getting an error -

RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QgsPrintLayout has been deleted

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer

fileName = 'D:\\UCC\\exported' # exported is a prefix for the file names
boundaryLayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Cooling_Towers')[0]
QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayer(boundaryLayer.id()).setItemVisibilityChecked(True)

otherLayers = []
for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
    if layer.name().startswith("M_"):
        otherLayers.append(layer.name())

count = 0
def prepareMap(): # Arrange layers
    for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
        if layer.name().startswith("M_"):
            QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayer(layer).setItemVisibilityChecked(False)
    for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
        if layer.name().startswith(otherLayers[count]):
            QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayer(layer).setItemVisibilityChecked(True)
            qgis.utils.iface.setActiveLayer(layer)
            qgis.utils.iface.zoomToActiveLayer()
            project = QgsProject.instance()
            manager = project.layoutManager()
            layout = QgsPrintLayout(project)
            layoutName = 'Layout'
            #initializes default settings for blank print layout canvas
            layout.initializeDefaults()
            layout.setName(layoutName)
            manager.addLayout(layout)
            #layoutName = "PrintLayout"
            layouts_list = manager.printLayouts()
            # remove any duplicate layouts
            for layout in layouts_list:
                if layout.name() == layoutName:
                    manager.removeLayout(layout)
            
            page_size =QgsLayoutSize(5000, 5000, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutPixels)
            pc = layout.pageCollection()
            page = pc.pages()[0]
            page.setPageSize(page_size)

            # create map item in the layout
            map = QgsLayoutItemMap(layout)
            map.setKeepLayerSet(True)
            map.setLayers([layer, boundaryLayer])
            map.setRect(20, 20, 20, 20)
            
            #rect = QgsRectangle(ms.fullExtent())
            rect = QgsRectangle(-8232312.3, 4993694.4, -8231302.8, 4994703.9)
            map.setExtent(rect)
            map.attemptResize(QgsLayoutSize(423.333, 423.333, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
            layout.addLayoutItem(map)
                       
            layout = manager.layoutByName(layoutName)
            exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)

            fn = 'D:\\layout_export' + str(count) + '.png'
            exporter.exportToImage(fn, QgsLayoutExporter.ImageExportSettings())
            
            
            #map.refresh()
            
    QTimer.singleShot(30000, exportMap) # Wait a second and export the map

 # Save the map as a PNG
def exportMap():
    global count # We need this because we'll modify its value
    if count < len(otherLayers)-1:
        QTimer.singleShot(10000, prepareMap) # Wait a second and prepare next map
    count += 1

prepareMap()
```

Reference - [Iterating over layers and exporting them as PNG images with PyQGIS in standalone script](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/189735/iterating-over-layers-and-exporting-them-as-png-images-with-pyqgis-in-standalone/333486#333486)

https://data.library.virginia.edu/how-to-create-and-export-print-layouts-in-python-for-qgis-3/

Answer (score 1):

This error appears when you print a layout with a name that is already used for other layout.

Comment: Ok.. How could I resolve it? I mean what changes should I do with my code? @Mayo

Comment: There are many ways to do this, the important think is that every layout must have a different name and in your code you are naming all the layouts "Layout". You can name each layouts with the name of the layer you are printing: `layoutName = layer.name()`.