# Exporting ALL selected raster layers in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, export

I am working in QGIS 3.8.3 in Windows 10,

**I have to export all the selected raster layers, is there any way of doing this instead of exporting them one by one?**

I only would like to export all of them to the same format, all of them have the same resolution and also the same latitude/longitude size.

I haven't found help page of [QGis](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/training_manual/spatial_databases/import_export.html?highlight=export), and I am totally new to python codes, so I seek any 'easy' to understand or well explained "how to apply the code".

Comment: Try the code described in the answer for this post: [Export raster layer in python to specific folder](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/189590/export-raster-layer-in-python-to-specific-folder). If you have any more problems, [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/338783/edit) your post to include the details so that others could help :)